# Open new tab on table row click in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

In my project, I have a dynamic table. Click on any of the row of table new tab should get open and I can pass the data as well to the new tab. How can I do this using angular 6? Basically I want to call another component on click of table row in new tab.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.open()`.

By default, it opens in a new tab.

Add a route in your router to perform the navigation to the component.
You can treat the parameters in the route.

## Precisions on the answer:

You can declare the route like that:

```js
//router 
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
```

You can next retrieve in your component the parameter :

```js
// Component code

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
  private service: HeroService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.service.getHero(params.get('id')))
  );
}
```

For more info, follow the guide https://angular.io/guide/router

## From [Showy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12469950/showy) suggestion

From the documentation that can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) :

> The open() method opens a new browser window, or a new tab, **depending on your browser settings** and the parameter values.

From what I tested on Chrome with default settings, `window.open('fooLink/')` is opening a new tab.

Comment: Be aware of window.open(). If I'm correct this command will most likely open a new window instead of new tab even if you pass '_blank'

Comment: From the documentation of the function you are partially right. 
```The open() method opens a new browser window, or a new tab, depending on your browser settings and the parameter values.```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

By default it opens a new tab, if the browser settings allows it.

Comment: @Showy, I updated my answer crediting you on the precision. Feel free to update my post to add clarification on this behaviour if you have more information about window.close().

Answer (score 1):

**Different tabs are different app instances, you cannot pass data between tabs.**

**Unless you pass the data as parameter in the new opened tab route.**

I mean your routing should have an url which accepts parameters, like this:

in the row html you should have something like:

```
<a href="urlTo/example/test1/test2/test3" target="_blank"></a>
```

In your routings you should have:

```
{
  path: 'example/:param1/:param2/:param3',
  component: YourComponent
}
```